# newbie in Eclipse _ how to find text?

Tags: eclipse

Warning: It is not programming related question ...I just want to know how can any text I can find from whole folder which I select for find?
crtl+f finds a text only in a open document ...but what if i want to know it from whole document ..like in dreamweaver ..when we do ctrl+f it fives trhe option to select folder
...

is there any option in eclipse too ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225761/cutomize-searchfile-function-in-eclipse/3225824#3225824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu Search -> File

Some tips:

1. To find only on selected folder you can click the option **Selected resources**
2. You can define a keybinding for File Search from Preferences -> General -> Keys. Look for Command *File Search*

Answer (score 1):

Using `Ctrl + H` would give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Hit Ctrl+L for a quick look at the shortcuts available in Eclipse. Ctrl+L+L (L twice on hold of Ctrl) will let you customize the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, should bring up the search that will include options to search via project, directory, etc.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> can be used to find selected text across a workspace in eclipse.